# Kotlin how to mock function in parameters

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, mockito

I've tried to cover presenter with test. Presenter use case as DataSource. Execute method of use case has following structure: `fun execute(params: TInput? = null, onNext: (TOutput) -> Unit, onError: (Throwable) -> Unit)`.

My question is how I can mock emit from onNext and onError?

Here is my PresenterTest:

```
class AssignmentsPresenterTest : UnitTest() {

    @Mock lateinit var dataRepository: IDataRepository
    @Mock lateinit var viewState: AssignmentsView

    lateinit var execute: ExecuteUseCase
    lateinit var presenter: AssignmentsPresenter


    @Before fun setUp() {
        execute = ExecuteUseCase(dataRepository)
        presenter = AssignmentsPresenter()
        presenter.attachView(viewState)
    }

    @Test fun `should return list of assignments`() {
        given {
            execute.execute(anyVararg(), { }, { })
        }.willReturn(anyVararg())
    }
}
```

Presenter code:

```
@InjectViewState
class AssignmentsPresenter : BasePresenter<AssignmentsView>() {

    @Inject lateinit var executeUseCase: ExecuteUseCase
    private var items: MutableList<AssignmentExpandableModel> = mutableListOf()

    init {
        BTApplication.getApplicationComponent()?.mainComponent()?.inject(this)
    }

    fun getAssignments(text: String? = null) {
        viewState.showLoading()
        executeUseCase.execute(
                 onNext = { handleSuccessDefault(it) },
                 onError = { handleError(it) })
    }
}
```

UseCase code:

```
class ExecuteUseCase @Inject constructor(private val dataRepository: IDataRepository)
    : UseCase.RxObservable<ExecutePresentationQuery, AssignmentWrapper>() {

    override fun build(params: ExecutePresentationQuery?): Observable<AssignmentWrapper> {
        return dataRepository.execute(it)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Log:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Invalid use of argument matchers!
>   0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
>   -> at com.bottomline.partnerselect.presentation.presenter.assignments.AssignmentsPresenterTest$should return list of assignments$1.invoke(AssignmentsPresenterTest.kt:30) //end bracket at the file
>
> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>       //incorrect:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
>   When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.

Comment: Could you show your presenter code?

Comment: @user8035311 added code

Comment: And what's your ExecuteUseCase ?

Comment: @user8035311 added usecase code

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @michalbrz I added logs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most important part in the error message is:

> When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.

And you have

```
execute.execute(anyVararg(), { }, { })
```

`anyVararg()` (btw. why not regular `any()`?) is a matcher, while `{}` is not.

`{}` is a normal function definition in Kotlin. It is a function (with zero or one argument) that does nothing.

So one of your argument is matcher, while others are not and it violates Mockito rules.

You can mock function the same way as a regular object (with mockito-kotlin):

```
val onNext = mock<(TOutput) -> Unit>()
```